# wordpress widget drag and drop not working after update to 3.5.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I use ata-pp5 theme with wordpress for my site,recently after i update my wordpress to3.5.1 now the drag and drop feature in the widget area is not working..,i already try  add Google Libraries plugin but it also did't work,

Comment: Press F12 and see what JavaScript errors are being displayed in the console.. that would be a good starting point

Comment: i already try with firebug seems to me there were no errors..

Comment: Well after quick googling, you're not the only one, so it'll be down to the actual theme code itself - you'll have to debug the PHP errors and any JavaScript conflicts there maybe. [Turn On PHP Errors](http://www.mjdigital.co.uk/blog/php-display-errors-at-runtime/) - Drag & Drop is probably just a jQuery attachment, see if jQuery is even being included or not firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Have you tried:***

=> Deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).

=> [Resetting the plugins folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) by FTP or PhpMyAdmin. Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of some faulty plugins .. there is fix of this problem and its pretty easy way to follow . Here is the solution
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UY0u-aZb-k