# Wordpress widget drag and drop is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is a problem with my wordpress site, my widget area drag and drop is not working.

I have updated my wordpress from old to latest version, I have searched this problem on internet and I used the following solution

1. Disable the plugins as mentioned here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358840/wordpress-widget-drag-and-drop-not-working-after-update-to-3-5-1) after disable all the plugin this is working fine , But if i activate a single plugin , does't matter which one , it stops working 
   the plugins I am using are 
   **All in one seo pack**
   **disques comment system** 
   **facebook like box**
   **social media feather**
   **star box**
   **wp-syntex**

2.I found a solution to this problem from internet to add:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

It didn't help

Main issue if I use a test file to check my php info with `phpinfo()` it does't show any thing.

**Update**

menu drag and drop is working correctly, but the screen option is not working at the top of the post and pages.

**update 2**

No error in the firebug console .

Comment: try to change the theme ..

Comment: Drag and Drop functionality is created by jQuery, So go to widgets page on Google chrome and press "F12" -> Console, and check which script is causing this issue.